# Classify tweets into categories with supervised machine learning Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, twitter, supervised-learning

I have a large set of tweets from which a small subset have all been manually assigned to topic categories. The categories are represented as numbers, 1 through 4, and each number has about twenty tweets underneath it that belong to that category. For example:

```
Category     Tweets

   1         ...twenty tweets belonging to category one...

   2         ...twenty tweets belonging to category two...

   3         ...twenty tweets belonging to category three...

   4         ...twenty tweets belonging to category four...
```

My goal is to implement some sort of machine learning technique, in Python specifically, that will be able to take the already classified tweets and their categories as training data for the algorithm, and then, using what it has learned, look through the rest of the data set and return about 100 tweets per category that it believes most belong to that category.

I have looked around at algorithms such as supervised LDA, labeled LDA, and K nearest neighbors, but I cannot understand how those algorithms would apply to my task. If anyone could link me to some resources it would be much appreciated, since I have been pulling my hair out over this!

Comment: As it is, the question is "too broad". I'd advice you to check whether basic Naive Bayes for text classification, with multinomial model does what you want, take this as baseline, then take a look at more complex models, then eventually come back with more concrete questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i am understanding your question correctly, you have a small subset of labelled data on which you wish to train the algorithm and then want to use that trained algorithm on a large set of data to get best 100 tweets for each category.

If this is the case, logistic regression can be useful as it is quite successful for text classification. Also it will give you a probability of each tweet being in the 4 classes

**For eg tweet 1 result will be like this [0.4,0.3,0.2,0.1]. This indicates that tweet 1 belongs to category 1. However, you can store these probabilities in a separate list and then sort them to get top 100.**

If you want to make it scalable, I would suggest using pyspark libraries since you are already familiar with python. Here is a handy tutorial

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-classification-regression.html#logistic-regression